# Redirect index page to inner page

Tags: wordpress

Suppose I have a WordPress domain, say `sampledomain.com`. By default, it will point to `index.php`.

What If I want, instead of the landing page – i.e. when some one types the domain name-
sampledomain.com – it should point to an inner page, like `sampledomain.com/property/home/`?

It is a WordPress site; I believe it should be achievable using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Please paste your code , what you are trying so for

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use `.htaccess` for that you can select any page that you want landing page for your wordpress theme.

Go to the `Settings->Readings` and select A static page like 
[image]

Select any page from Front Page dropdown menu that you want to display on front page. Still if you want redirection with `.htaccess` then this should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /my-target-page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, actually the page, which is supposed to be the target destination or redirected is not a Page I think it should be a post, actually it is published as Property and all published Properties are using posts feature of wordpress and not page..